# What subset of ARMA(1,1) processes can be represented as AR(1) - a query about the logic in this derivation

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

This is a section of an excellent paper by Granger and Morris (1976: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2345178) that shows how higher order ARMA models may be interpreted in terms of the sums of lower-order ARMA, AR and/or MA models. Some simple examples are shown in the test (such as that given below).

My question is this:  How are the inequalities in 5.3 (iv) constructed - I cannot see the logic in how they are derived.  Also, once one has these, how can they be used to find c and d?

[image: This is a section of text from a paper by Granger and Morris (1976)]

Comment: I assume that I know c = a (because it is obvious) and then if I have an ARMA(1,1) process I can find its ACF and then from ACF at lag 1 I can find d... so I can find the two parameters - the only question remaining is whether this combination of c and d is a valid way to represent AR(1) + WN as ARMA(1,1) ?

Comment: Doesn't it just mean that c > d ?

Comment: I think the title of your question is a bit misleading in that the question asked by Granger and Morris is what subset of ARMA(1,1) processes can be represented as AR(1) + white noise, not the other way around (as all AR(1) + white noise process can be represented as ARMA(1,1)).

Comment: @JarleTufto - thank you for that.  You are indeed correct and so I have modified my title.  However, just your prompt has been incredibly helpful.  Thank you!\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the ARMA(1,1) with parameters $c$, $d$ and $\sigma_\xi^2$ that is given.  The question is then what are the parameters of the AR(1)$+$white noise representation (if such a representation exist).  This is found by solving (5.3) w.r.t. $a$, $\sigma_\eta^2$ and $\sigma_\varepsilon^2$ which leads to
\begin{align}
   a&=c
\\ \sigma_\varepsilon^2&=\left(1+d^2 - \frac{1+c^2}c d \right)\sigma_\xi^2
\\ \sigma_\eta^2 &= \frac d c \sigma_\xi^2 
\end{align}
The solution for $\sigma_\varepsilon^2$ is non-negative only if $1+d^2 \ge \frac{1+c^2}c d$.  But the roots of the MA- and AR-polynomials in (5.2) needs to be distinct, $d\neq c$, so we must have $1+d^2 > \frac{1+c^2}c d$ equivalent to the first inequality
$$
\frac 1 {1+c^2}>\frac{d}{c(1+d^2)} = \frac{\rho_1}c.
$$
Similarly, the solution for $\sigma_\eta^2$ also needs to be non-negative implying that
$$
\frac d c \ge 0
$$
or
$$
\frac{\rho_1(1+d^2)}c \ge 0
$$
or
$$
\frac{\rho_1}c \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Great answer! How would one go about a similar argument to find the subset of ARMA(2,1) that could be represented by AR(1) + AR(1) ?

Comment: In much the same way.  Again you get two right hand sides that are MA(1) that need to have the same autocovariance functions for the representations to be equal.  This gives you two equations that you can solve for the white noise variances of the two AR(1) processes and these variances need to be non-negative.  In addition, the roots of the AR(2) polynomial needs to be real, such that each AR(1) process has real coefficients.

Comment: Thanks Jarle.  I have been trying to do this, but got rather stuck.  Having re-read your answer I think this might be because, in order to show how ARMA(2,1)  could be AR(1) + AR(1), I also have to show how MA(1) could be MA(1) + MA(1). I will investigate and post further...

Comment: In trying to answer the AR(1) + AR(1) question, I need to answer the MA(1) + MA(1) question, which in turn requires constraints for the MA(1) = MA(1) = white noise case.  I have created a new post outlining my tentative progress on this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498300/can-an-ma1-process-arise-from-a-different-ma1-process-plus-white-noise-if-s