# Can an MA(1) process arise from a different MA(1) process plus white noise? If so, what are the constraints on the parameters of the two processes?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

This is a question linked to an earlier discussion ([What subset of ARMA(1,1) processes can be represented as AR(1) - a query about the logic in this derivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497739/what-subset-of-arma1-1-processes-can-be-represented-as-ar1-a-query-about-t)) .

I am looking at the possibility of  MA(1) = MA(1) = white noise, with a view to then considering MA(1) = MA(1) + MA(1), (and the first needed for the second).  However I am unsure that my logic is correct - I have seen elsewhere a reference to a "solution", but I am only able to identify a potential range of parameters for the equivalent model.

I started with the simple case of an MA(1) representing a different MA(1) plus white noise as follows:

Is there an $\mathbf{MA}\left(1\right)$ process, $Z_t$ that can arise from the sum of a different $\mathbf{MA}\left(1\right)$ process, $X_t$ and $\textit{white noise}$, denoted $\xi_t$?

To begin we have:
\begin{equation}
X_t = \left(1+\alpha B\right)\varepsilon_t \quad \mbox{and} \quad Y_t = \xi_t \quad \mbox{so} \quad Z_t = \left(1+\theta B\right)\zeta_t = X_t + Y_t = \left(1+\alpha B\right)\varepsilon_t + \xi_t
\end{equation}
so we can say for the process $Z_t$:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{E}\left[Z_t\right] = 0, \quad \mathbf{Var}\left[Z_t\right] = \gamma_0 = \left(1+\theta^2\right)\sigma_{\zeta}^2 = \left(1+\alpha^2\right)\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2 + \sigma_{\xi}^2, \quad \mbox{and} \quad \gamma_1 = \theta\sigma_{\zeta}^2 = \alpha\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2
\end{equation}
For the series $Z_t$ to be equivalent to $X_t + Y_t$, then:
\begin{equation}
 \rho_1 = \frac{\theta}{\left(1+\theta^2\right)} = \frac{\alpha\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}{\left(1+\alpha^2\right)\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2 + \sigma_{\xi}^2} 
\end{equation}
For a given series, we would be able to determine $\rho_1$ and therefore $\theta$, but for this to be equivalent to another $\mathbf{MA}\left(1\right)$ series - $X_t$ - plus white noise - $\xi_t$ - then:
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{\xi}^2 = \left[\frac{\alpha\left(1+\theta^2\right)}{\theta} - \left(1+\alpha^2\right)\right]\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2 \quad \mbox{or} \quad \sigma_{\xi}^2 = \left[\frac{\alpha}{\rho_1} - \left(1+\alpha^2\right)\right]\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2 
\end{equation}
Given $\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2,\,\sigma_{\xi}^2 > 0$, then we have a condition linking $\alpha$ and $\theta$ to $\rho_1$:
\begin{equation}
 \left(1+\alpha^2\right) < \frac{\alpha\left(1+\theta^2\right)}{\theta} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{\alpha\left(1+\theta^2\right)}{\theta} = \frac{\alpha}{\rho_1} 
\end{equation}
For both $\mathbf{MA}\left(1\right)$ processes to be stationary, then $-1<\theta,\,\alpha<1$, which constrains the lag-1 autocorrelation coefficient thus $-0.5<\rho_1<0.5$. We can further consider the relationship between $\alpha$, $\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2$, $\sigma_{\xi}^2$ as constrained by $\rho_1$, as:\begin{equation}
\alpha^2 - \frac{\alpha}{\rho_1} + \left(1 + \frac{\sigma_{\xi}^2}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}\right) = 0 \quad \mbox{so} \quad \alpha = \frac{1}{2\rho_1}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-4\rho_1^2\left(\frac{\sigma_{\xi}^2}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}+1\right)}\right)
\end{equation}

so, given that $-1<\alpha<1$ for the model to be stationary, and that $\alpha$ must be real then:

\begin{equation}
 4\rho_1^2\left(\frac{\sigma_{\xi}^2}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}+1\right) < 1 \quad \mbox{such that} \quad \sigma_{\xi}^2 < \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2\left[\left(\frac{1}{2\rho_1}\right)^2 - 1\right]
\end{equation}

So, I can estimate a set of parameters $\alpha$, $\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2$ and $\sigma_{\xi}^2$ that will meet the necessary condition. Is this the complete resolution to the question, or is there other information that I have missed?

Comment: Hi: I don't have time to read exactly  what you're doing but I would ddo a literature search so that you don't re-invent a difficult wheel.  The guy who did a lot of that is o.d anderson. I'm not sure if this is the book that has it but I would check it out first before you start doing what you're doing. Also, check out the time-series literature on the same topic.  https://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-Forecast-D-Anderson/dp/040870926X/ref=sr_1_17?dchild=1&keywords=o.d+anderson+time+series&qid=1606488503&sr=8-17

Comment: One other thing: I'm not sure how you came up with your topic but, if you're advisor suggested it, sometimes even they don't know what has already been done or considered. Or maybe he wants you to do it on your own anyway for exercise ? Still, I would check out O.D Anderson. He's a quirky figure. Not very well known but he did a lot. And don't get him mixed up with T.W !!!!

Comment: @mlofton - very useful, thanks. I am actually an academic from a different field trying to figure our how to manipulate these approaches to suit a very particular purpose.  I have been trawling the literature for some time but have found very little to go on except for the Granger and Morris paper - but I will now go look for OD Anderson!

Comment: Hi: Yes, it's not an easy topic to find but it's there somewhere. I looked at it maybe a 4 or 5 years ago. I'll try to find something when I have some time. My apologies for labelling you as a grad student but it sounded like something an advisor might give to a grad student. IIRC, the other literature that I found was document oriented rather than book. But, as far as books, I'm pretty sure that the one in the link I sent has some material.

Comment: It's not comprehensive but I will send five links in each of the next five comments that are relevant to what you're looking at. For two of them, you need jstor which you hopefully have. All the best.

Comment: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams586/SUM.pdf

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1984.tb00384.x

Comment: https://eml.berkeley.edu/~powell/e241b_f06/TS-ARMA.pdf

Comment: http://people.stern.nyu.edu/churvich/Forecasting/Handouts/Chapt3.3.pdf

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4615673?seq=1

Comment: One more. ( this is bringing back memories so it's hard to stop looking ). Problem # 2 in this is really interesting and the same site has a solution.  http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~stein/26100/2008/

Comment: @mlofton - thanks, that's great.  I have in fact been following the first (ams.sunysb.edu) paper, which is helpful but does that thing that lots of mathematicians do - its gets to a point and then say"and from here we solve for ...." but without showing how! For a non-mathematician this causes. a problem! Where is problem 2 in the last link please - it took me to a blank page?

Comment: I hate that thing where they don't show the details. they think it's obvious and we don't !!!!! And sorry for blank page. I'll send another link that's hopefully the correct one this time.

Comment: :If you click on the link I sent, you're right, it's pretty blank. But then, if you click on homework and then homework 7 and homework 7 partial solutions, question # 2 is relevant. I hope it helps.

Comment: and if you have questions about "it can be easily shown", usually someone here can help. Once in a while me but not often !!!!!!